# Help proving a little theorem about inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm working through Spivak, and I'm stuck on this question:

Given that: $$|x-x_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$$$|y-y_o|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Show that: $$|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|<\epsilon$$$$|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|<\epsilon$$

By adding the two given inequalities together, I get:$$|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|<\epsilon$$

By analyzing the various cases for the two absolute values, it follows that the two desired results hold for specific cases. I can't seem to get the general case though. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Rearrange and apply the triangle inequality. i.e. $|(x+y) - (x_0 + y_0)| = |(x-x_0) + (y - y_0)| \leq (...) < \varepsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality we have
 $$|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|=|(x-x_0)+(y-y_0)|\le|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|<2\times\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon$$
and the second inequality is similar.